# How to show div when user reach bottom of the page?

Tags: jquery, fadein, viewport

When user scrolls to the bottom of the page I want to show some div, with jQuery of course. And if user scrolls back to he top, div fade out.
So how to calculate viewport (or whatever is the right name) :)

Thanks

Comment: are you talking about a div that will have a position:fixed; or a div that is just at the bottom of the content?

Comment: it will be fixed position at the bottom of the page, maybe "bottom:50px"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This must get you started:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2768264</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                    if ($('body').height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
                        alert('Bottom reached!');
                    }
                });
            });    
        </script>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p
        <p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p
        <p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p
        <p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p
    </body>
</html>
```

This assumes that `body` has a `margin` of `0`. Else you'll need to add the top and bottom margin to the `$('body').height()`.

Comment: Did you check the margins? I updated the answer to include an SSCCE.

Comment: Yea, margin is 0, I'm using CSS reset. And also Im using jQuery 1.3.2?

Comment: Hmm, you're right, it didn't work in Firefox (Editplus here has IE7 as builtin browser). The viewport is actually higher in FF. I'll investigate if that's to be expected. Update: funny, `body.onscroll` is not supported in FF.

Comment: I replaced `body.onscroll` by `window.onscroll` and `==` by `<=`.

Comment: I found misstake, it should be: $(window).scroll not $('body') Thanks

Comment: Is there anyway to show content when user reach bottom-200px, for example. So not exactly the bottom, rather than 200px before? Thanks one more time

Comment: Substract the body height with this value.

Comment: awesome! from this code it's possible to develop also something similar like on facebook or twitter. awesome! wonderful :)

Comment: You could better use `$(document).height()` instead of `$('body').height()`. The body returned me the wrong height in my design.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
        //Bottom Reached
    }
});
```

I use this because i have

```
body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I was exactly in the same case. Your solution worked for me !

Comment: @Adrien You're welcome my friend. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a small edit on the BalusC's code if you want to show a div not a javascript popup:

```
<head>
    <title>SO question 2768264</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($("body").height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
                    $("#hi").css("display","block");
                }else {
                    $("#hi").css("display","none");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        #hi {
          background: red; color: #FFF; position: fixed; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; display: none;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p
    <p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p
    <p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p
    <p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p<p>p

    <div id="hi">HIIIIIIIIIIII</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi. Let's say instead of "body" I'm using a div ID and what if I want the "hi" to appear when I'm at 80% of the scrolled div, for example? :) Vote up will pay a good answer :)

Answer (score 2):

$(document).[scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)() should give you the position of scrollbar.
you check that against document height. then fade in or out the div.