# Displaying a Div depending on a condition

Tags: jquery

I have seen pages which display div's when the user scrolls to the end of the page. When the user starts scrolling up, the div disappears. How can I do this in jQuery. I am using v1.8

So far I have tried this

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert('bottom')
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768264/how-to-show-div-when-user-reach-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7EzUf/

You put your code in a `.scroll` handler for the `window` element. The function will be fired whenever the user scrolls.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $('#bottom').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#bottom').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: is there also a way to fire the event only once when the user continues scrolling at reaching bottom?

Answer (score 2):

You have to check that on scrolling:

```
var $win = $(window),
    $doc = $(document),
    $target = $('#target');
// save relevant elements so they don't have to be selected on each scroll call

$win.scroll(function() {
    $win.scrollTop() + $win.height() == $doc.height()
    ? $target.show()
    : $target.hide();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4WEX/)

Answer (score 0):

See it working here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcwEq/)

the alert div appears when you hit the bottom other wise hides