# JQuery - Begginner Issue with Conditional

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having trouble making the following conditional revert the elements to its default CSS if it's false.

What the function does is animate some elements CSS beyond a certain point in scroll (specifically when those element's container - a fixed navbar - is scrolled above another div).

The function Works correctly when I scroll down but if I go back (if the variable offsetDiv > offsetNav) it doesn't "revert" to the defaults as I wanted it to. What's the issue here, please?

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var offsetDiv = $('div').offset().top;
  var offsetNav = $('nav').offset().top;

  if (offsetDiv <= offsetNav){
    $('nav').animate({borderTopWidth:"0px",backgroundColor:"#44217A"},200);
    $('#logosmall').animate({width:"120px",height:"120px"},200);
    $('nav>ul>li>a').animate({lineHeight:"120px"},200);
  }
  else {       
    $('nav').animate({borderTopWidth:"20px",backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0)"},200);
    $('#logosmall').animate({width:"140px",height:"140px"},200);
    $('nav>ul>li>a').animate({lineHeight:"140px"},200); // These are "CSS defaults". I put them here again because I thought the condition being false would trigger this.
  }
)};
```

**CSS**

```
nav {position:fixed};
#logosmall {width:140px;height:140px};
nav>ul>li>a {line-height:140px;};
```

Comment: I would suggest to do some debugging here: Start simple, underneath the offsetDiv and offsetNav var declarations, put something like this: console.log("offsetDiv", offsetDiv); console.log("offsetNav", offsetNav); Then open the dev console in the browser to look, what the values are while scrolling, you might get some insight into the problem.

Comment: Thanks, @ghost23. I wasn't familiar with debugging. I'll try that.

Comment: It would help a lot if you made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your html actually showing the issue

Comment: Here is a similar question and answer that might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577436/show-div-at-top-of-page-hide-when-scrolling-then-show-div-at-bottom-of-page/27577983#27577983

Comment: @DelightedD0D I will do a JSFiddle asap. I appreciate you sending this link. After a few tests I believe it's a problem with the animate method. I simplified my function and changed the method to fadeIn and fadeOut with only one element to study the behavior and it the conditional worked correctly.

Comment: @DelightedD0D Here's a fiddle of the original function https://jsfiddle.net/Lfyt3xLn/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfyt3xLn/13/) shows, your annimations do appear to be applied when you want them to. (watch the console output in the fiddle)

I think part of your problem is that you cant animate things like `background-color` with `.animate()`

If you wan't to animate background color, you'll need to use something like jQuery UI. Good news is, if you're willing to use jQuery UI, you can use [`.switchClass()`](https://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/) to make this all a cinch like this:

#### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfyt3xLn/16/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var $nav = $('.my-nav')
    var $logo = $('.logosmall')
    var $link = $('.link')
    var offsetDiv = $("#white").offset().top;
    var offsetNav = $link.offset().top;
    if (offsetDiv <= offsetNav) {
      $nav.switchClass('up', 'down', 400);
      $logo.switchClass('up', 'down', 400);
      $link.switchClass('up', 'down', 400);
    } else {
      $nav.switchClass('down', 'up', 400);
      $logo.switchClass('down', 'up', 400);
      $link.switchClass('down', 'up', 400);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.my-nav.up {
  position: fixed;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 20px solid green;
}

.my-nav.down {
  position: fixed;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 0px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.logosmall.up {
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.logosmall.down {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.link.up {
  line-height: 140px;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.link.down {
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

div#heroimage {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

div#white {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<nav class="my-nav up">
  <div class="logosmall up"></div>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="link up">Link 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="heroimage"></div>
<div id="white"></div>
```

Comment: This is interesting! switchClass() is AMAZING. I'll try and implement that. Thanks a lot!