# show a div when the top of the screen touches another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I'm trying to make a div appear and disappear by using jquery with scroll. I want it to appear when the div called "contingut-pagina" appears on the screen, the code shown below is working, but it changes the classe when it touches the bottom of the screen and I want it to do so when the div touches the top . 
It's possible? I copy the current code here:

```
function viewportCustom() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > ($(".contingut-pagina").position().top - $(window).height())) {
            $(".block-simplified-social-share").css("opacity", "1");
        }
        if($(window).scrollTop() < ($(".contingut-pagina").position().top - $(window).height())) {
            $(".block-simplified-social-share").css("opacity", "0");
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You should be using bottom in the second condition.

Comment: if I use bottom the only thing that changes is that it appears when going through the end of the div, but I do not want this. I want it to change when the top of the div goes through the top of the screen.

Comment: are you using the bottom in first condition or second, use second condition to as else if

Comment: You mean this?

if($(window).scrollTop() < ($(".contingut-pagina").position().bottom - $(window).height())) {
   $(".block-simplified-social-share").css("opacity", "0");
  }

by doing this the content disappears when I pass through the end of the div.

I use two conditions. One to appear and the other to disappear, in this case what I try is that the share buttons appear below, after the header and disappear when user return to the top of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution using .offset(), now it works like I want. Thanks to all

```
function viewportCustom() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.contingut-pagina').offset().top){
            $('.block-simplified-social-share').css("opacity", "1");

        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < $('.contingut-pagina').offset().top){
            $('.block-simplified-social-share').css("opacity", "0");

        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do let me know if it works, here's the solution:

```
function viewportCustom() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > ($(".contingut-pagina").position().top - $(window).height())) {
        $(".block-simplified-social-share").css("opacity", "1");
    }else if($(window).scrollTop() < ($(".contingut-pagina").position().bottom - $(window).height())) {
        $(".block-simplified-social-share").css("opacity", "0");
    }
})
}
```

You can also seek the help of this blog:
[How to show div when user reach bottom of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768264/how-to-show-div-when-user-reach-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: Can you please create the jsfiddle or codepen for the same.?